# sqlplus in oracle: second column is wrapped/shows up on next line instead of the same line as first

Tags: oracle, formatting, sqlplus

I have a formatting question for you all today.

I'm using the `listagg` function for the first time and I get the results I want, but the second column is getting wrapped around and appearing on the line underneath column1. I have adjusted my linesizes and everything, but still get the same issue. Keep in mind that I am working with sqlplus in an oracle environment.

**Here is the query:**

```
select lit_id "Bookid",listagg(Auname, ',')
        WITHIN GROUP
        (order by Auname) "Author"
        from LITWORK_AUTHOR
        group by lit_id;
```

**Here is what I get:**

```
    Bookid
----------
Author
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      1101
Dilbert,Emerson,Sartre

      1102
Axel,Sartre

      1103
Breese,Marquez

      1104
Groom,Young

      1105
Blake,Julian,Scott,Verde,Young

      1106
Black,Sartre

      2007
Emerson,Pell,Simon

      2008
Codd,Rogers,Sartre,Young

8 rows selected.
```

**This is what I want:** (example of first few lines)

```
Bookid   Author
  1101   Dilbert,Emerson,Sartre
  1102   Axel,Sartre
  1103   Breese,Marquez
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you use the `COLUMN` command (SQL\*Plus command!) to format the two columns? Is `BOOKID` a `NUMBER` column? Then you could try to format the two columns with `COLUMN BOOKID FORMAT 99999 ` and `COLUMN AUTHOR FORMAT A50`.

Comment: That worked!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @SQLinTraining : I suggest you write an answer yourself mentioning the column commands which worked for you . It might be helpful to search engines and future visitors.

Comment: @KaushikNayak - I agree; good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
COLUMN Bookid Format 99999

COLUMN Author Format A50

select lit_id "Bookid",listagg(Auname, ',')
      WITHIN GROUP
      (order by Auname) "Author"
      FROM LITWORK_AUTHOR
      GROUP BY lit_id;
```

This got the exact format that I wanted